# Writing variables from GUI to text file in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write the text fields values to a file like this (where inputtxt is a Text widget):

```
    input_file_name =   inputtxt1.get('1.0', 'end-1c').replace(" ","")
    num_of_compare_points = inputtxt2.get('1.0','end-1c')
    VER = inputtxt3.get('1.0','end-1c')
    mode = inputtxt4.get(1.0','end-1c')
    executionMode = inputtxt5.get('1.0','end-1c')
    numOfWorkers = inputtxt6.get ('1.0','end-1c')
    sessionFile = inputtxt7.get('1.0','end-1c')

    file = open("file_1.setup","w")
         file.write (input_file_name + "\n" + num_of_compare_points + "\n" +    Option+"\n"+VER+"\n"+mode+"\n"+executionMode+"\n"+numOfWorkers+"\n"+sessionFile)
```

This method was good but I want to write the variable name +the value to the file so that the user can fill the values from the file not only through GUI and the order in file will be irrelevant since we're storing in the variable itself   , Example:
File_1.setup:
input_file_name = (some name the user can change it from here not from GUI)
num_of_compare_points = (some number the user can change it from here not from GUI)
.
.
.
etc
**UPDATE: I'm using the file attribute:value in a restore finction which put the value of each attribute on its related text field ; the problem here that I have only the value but not the variable:value and the variables must be in order (I need the order to be irrelevent since I'll use the variable name)**

```
def restore_info():

if os.stat('file_1.setup').st_size == 0:
    print("Writing to setup file..")
else:
    with open('file_1.setup','r') as f:
    
            lines = list(line for line in (l.strip() for l in f) if line)
    x = len(lines)
    print (x)
    for i in lines:
        print (i)                   
    if (x==7):
        inputtxt1.insert('end',lines[0])
        inputtxt2.insert('end',lines[1])
        inputtxt3.insert['end',lines[2])
        ... etc
```

**UPDATE2 : I've managed to split each line based on ":" but I need a way to tell the program where is variable and where is value**

```
def restore_info():

if os.stat('file_1.setup').st_size == 0:
    print("Writing to setup file..")
else:
    with open('file_1.setup','r') as f:
    
            lines = list(line for line in (l.strip() for l in f) if line)
    x = len(lines)
    print (x)
    for i in lines:
        splitted_i=i.split(":")
        print (splitted_i)
```

UPDATE 3:Advantage of this step

1. User will be able to apply the value manually, and not only through GUI.
2. The order will be irrelevant.
3. Any amount of spaces should be allowed around and in between the variable name and its value.
4. It will be very easy to search file_1.setup and extract the value for each field.

Comment: You have already defined what you want in the output file, so what is the problem on implementing it?

Comment: I need to store it as variable:value form , since I need to read the content of this file and put it in the text fields (when calling restore_previous options button) ; and the user can  fill the file manually and have different order than this . For example: write  the version in first line and then the file name in third line so in case we have version as variable we don't care about the order . Hope it's clear now @acw1668

Comment: No you just state what you want again, but not state what is the problem you came across when you tried to do it.

Comment: Updated .please check @acw1668

Comment: Your update still have nothing related to how you tried to save those *variable: value* pairs and reading the file to update corresponding *variables* based on the *variable: value* pairs.

Comment: This is actually what I need help in ,, I tried to read only the value but I need a way to read and store variable:value in a normal file format not json. 
@acw1668

Comment: I have new update please check @acw1668

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need to do is to collect the data into a dict and dump it as key value pair

```
sessionFile = 'x'
executionMode = 'y'
data = {'sessionFile': sessionFile, 'executionMode': executionMode}
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in data.items():
        f.write(f'{k}:{v}\n')
```

out.txt

```
sessionFile:x
executionMode:y
```

Comment: Thanks , but I want the format of file to be a multiple lines , not json file . Is there a way to do this?
@balderman

Comment: Sure. Loop over the dict items and write each key,val pair in new line.

Comment: Is there another way than json at all ?  I'm trying the method in the comments if you can check and help in it.
@balderman

Comment: Update the post and how the expected final file text.

Comment: I cant see the output file example that I have asked you to add to the post.

Comment: code was **updated**

Comment: Thanks very much!, now I'm trying to read each variable in the text file and put its value in its text field ; can you please show a short example how this can be done? @balderman

Comment: Give it a try. I am sure you can do it yourself. Ease accept the answer

Comment: Give it a try. I am sure you can do it yourself. Ease accept the answer

Comment: Accepted . I think I've reurned to the same point in UPDATE 2 (in the question) , or is there another way of doing it without splitting lines based on ": "

Comment: what is wrong with splitting on `:` ?

Comment: I have all the variables as one list and all values as another list so how can I for example test if a variable == sessionFile? variables [0] is the first letter of each variable

Comment: Use a dict, not a list.

Comment: what I want is to check what's this variable and writes its value to the text field and this doen't happen when I splitted on ":"

Comment: I used dict but had this error:  lines = dict(line for line in (l.strip() for l in f) if line)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 63; 2 is required

Comment: l.strip().split(':')